# How can I access class properties which is imported in a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm trying to declare class variable in a function and access its properties in another function however I'm getting error 1120. Here's my code:

```
// function content
if (components == "settings")
{
    import DialogComponentsSettings;
    var dialogComponentsSettings:DialogComponentsSettings = new DialogComponentsSettings();
    addChild(dialogComponentsSettings);
    dialogComponentsSettings.init();
    back_mc.addChild(dialogComponentsSettings.settings_mc);

    dialogComponentsSettings.okBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onOkClick);
    dialogComponentsSettings.cancelBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCancelClick);
}

private function onOkClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var arr:Array = new Array();
    arr[0] = e.target.name;
    arr[1] = dialogComponentsSettings.cb.selected;
    arr[2] = dialogComponentsSettings.ns.value;
    arr[3] = dialogComponentsSettings.ta.text;
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, arr));
}
```

This is giving me error:

*... \PopupDialog.as, Line 129, Column 13   1120: Access of undefined property dialogComponentsSettings.*

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try to put together an example on http://wonderfl.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `dialogComponentsSettings` is a local variable of that function. It is unknown outside of that function. That's why you receive the error.

You should declare the variable outside the function. This way it is available in other functions as well.

Placing an `import` into an if block doesn't make too much sense: the if condition is evaluated at run time, the import statement at compile time.

Always place your imports at the beginning of your code. That makes it clear what imports are used and saves other developers trying to read your code the hassle of finding those deeply nested imports, somewhere hidden in your code.

Comment: but if create many local variables outside the function, won't them hold place in memory?

Comment: I don't want to create many variables outside the functions. That's why I'm using seperate class files.

Comment: @nikel yes, exactly, you only need one variable: `dialogComponentsSettings`, the class groups all there is to this dialog into one object and you only need one variable to reference it. You do not need a separate variables for the ok and cancel button, because you can reference them via the object as you do already. Of course you want the object to stay in memory. After all you want to display it!

Comment: If you want to use any objects then they have to be in memory, if you don't want an object in memory then you can't use it anywhere.